# ASUS ROG Strix B450-f - Cannot enter BIOS, white LED permanently on, but can boot into Windows and GPU working fine

Tags: asus

So this is an odd one - I recently bought a ASUS ROG Strix B450, installed all of the components including an RX580.

Initially it wouldn't boot past the white LED (GPU error) on the mobo so I swapped the RX580 out for a simple NVIDIA card which allowed me to enter the BIOS and perform a BIOS update.

I rebooted and everything worked fine.

I put my RX580 back in, it booted fine into Windows 10, but no BIOS splash screen appeared, the white LED is still on permanently and I cannot get into the BIOS anymore via either the Windows 10 reboot feature or via the 'DEL' key on bootup.

Anyone have any ideas?

Using the NVIDIA card seemed to just work fine so is there a fundamental problem with the RX580 on this mobo and BIOS?

Comment: Have you consulted the motherboard's manual, which should have the troubleshooting steps? You may also want to reach out to ASUS tech support, as they may be able to provide you a custom built DOS boot executable to fash the BIOS _(this is different than a BIOS update, as it completely re-writes the BIOS chip, which is why a custom-built DOS boot executable is required - server board manufacturers offer this, so it's likely it's possible on regular motherboards as well)_

Comment: When in windows disable hibernation, restart and see if you can enter bios now.

Comment: See if you can access the UEFI by going to "Advanced Startup Options" in Windows. It will give you the option to reboot directly to the UEFI from a troubleshooting menu there.

Comment: @Moab  tried that, still skips POST and goes straight into Windows.

Comment: @SamForbis again goes straight into Windows..